# Finding subset of an array resulting maximum sum

Tags: algorithm

This is an algorithm 101 problem:

Given an array of N elements fund the subset of the array that results in maximum sum.
For example if my array is {1, -3, 5, -2, 9, -8, -6, 4} then the answer should be {5, -2, 9}.

So far I have an O(N^2) solution: For each index i of array, I compute the sum the subarrays if index (i,j) for all j > i; keeping track of the maximum, the lower index and upper index for the corresponding maximum along the way. Then I increment i and repeat the procedure until i < length of array.

I am wondering if I can do better than this. I am just looking for a right direction. From my math background something rings the bell that if I could keep track of the derivative and second derivative along the way this might somehow give a clue but so far I am kind of stuck with this problem for a while.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

Comment: it's not a *subset*, it's a continuous range

Comment: Read also: [Minimum Subarray which is larger than a Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157097/minimum-subarray-which-is-larger-than-a-key)

Comment: Thanks! I did not know this problem had a specific name.

Comment: Can the array be modified?

Comment: This has been asked many times.

Comment: See Chen Pang's beautiful code and adapt it to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839769/the-max-product-of-consecutive-elements-in-an-array/18840236#18840236

Comment: For subset, pick the positive numbers. For sub-array, use Kadane's algorithm.